# "To run a picture". Does it mean "publish"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

**"Sonia do you think that the UK media have done the right thing not to run these pictures.**" [ITV-this morning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UdJjIYsdY24) (see:1:40-1:48)

The expression **"to run a picture**" caught my attention. I looked it up, but couldn't find any definition.

Still, from the context, I can understand it seems to mean **"to publish a picture"**. What I wonder is why they are using **"run"**. Is it **"distinct"** from **"publish"**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

["To run a story"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/run%20a%20story) is an idiom in journalism:

> to print an article

It means print a news story (also broadcast on TV/radio or publish/post for digital media). "To run a picture" uses this format for photographs. It means to print, publish, broadcast or post a picture.

You can also find other examples of the same idiom e.g. "The newspaper **ran with** the headline '*Dewey Defeats Truman'*".

Comment: I think a possible distinction between “run” and “publish” might be that “publish” only implies that the public can see it, while “run” implies that the newspaper is putting its reputation behind the veracity of the story or picture.

Comment: @Timwi: I believe "run" originally was a literal reference to a "printing run" (i.e. one iteration of running the printing press to produce a pile of physical newspapers that you would then distribute). Obviously in the age of digital media, it is now mostly figurative (but physical newspapers do still exist...).

Comment: I would say, "*The newspaper **ran** the headline*", not "run with". To run with something is a phrasal verb with a different meaning. But if your quote is a real quote, please cite the source and tag me so I can delete this comment

Comment: @gotube while my example isn't a real quote, the phrase "ran with" is common. For example: https://www.theguardian.com/media/2022/jan/22/how-boris-johnson-alienated-the-whole-british-media and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coverage_of_the_Hillsborough_disaster_by_The_Sun